# Unable to properly add custom views on click at x,y position in relative layout

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

i have an issue with inserting custom views into my relative layout that takes only a part of the screen. When the activity loads it should populate views with specific width and height at x,y position that i get from my server, then when i click insert mode and click on the relative layout it should draw the view where i clicked as well...The problem is, sometimes it draws rectangle(should be square), sometimes just a line, sometimes nothing. It behaves differently if i change my width and height.

Custom view :

```
public class TableView extends View {

    private static final String TAG = "TableView";
    private int numberOfSeats;
    private int tableId;
    private int positionX;
    private int positionY;
    private int objectWidth;
    private int objectHeight;
    private boolean isTaken;
   private  String tableKind;


     private Rect rectangle;
    private Paint paint;


   /* public TableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }*/
    public TableView(Context context,int numberOfSeats,int tableId,int positionX,int positionY,int width,int height
    ,boolean isTaken, String tableKind) {
        super(context);

        this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
        this.tableId = tableId;
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
        this.objectWidth = width;
        this.objectHeight = height;
        this.isTaken = isTaken;
        this.tableId = tableId;
        this.tableKind = tableKind;

        //defining shape
        rectangle = new Rect(positionX,positionY,width,height);
        //defining shape color
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        Log.i(TAG, "TableView: tableId: "+tableId+" isTaken: "+isTaken);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int desiredWidth = objectWidth;
        int desiredHeight = objectHeight;

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int width;
        int height;

        //Measure Width
        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            //Must be this size
            width = widthSize;
        } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            //Can't be bigger than...
            width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
        } else {
            //Be whatever you want
            width = desiredWidth;
        }

        //Measure Height
        if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            //Must be this size
            height = heightSize;
        } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            //Can't be bigger than...
            height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
        } else {
            //Be whatever you want
            height = desiredHeight;
        }

        //MUST CALL THIS
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);

    }

    public int getNumberOfSeats() {
        return numberOfSeats;
    }

    public int getTableId() {
        return tableId;
    }

    public int getPositionX() {
        return positionX;
    }

    public int getPositionY() {
        return positionY;
    }

    public int getObjectWidth() {
        return objectWidth;
    }

    public int getObjectHeight() {
        return objectHeight;
    }

    public boolean isTaken() {
        return isTaken;
    }

    public String getTableKind() {
        return tableKind;
    }
}
```

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int numberOfSeats = 1;
    int tableId = 0;
    int positionX = 100;
    int positionY = 208;
    boolean isTaken = true;
    String tableKind = "table";
    int objectWidth =200;
    int objectHeight=200;

    TextView topTable;
    RelativeLayout floorPlan ;
    Button saveBtn ;

    private boolean insertTableCheck = false;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private int idTest = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        topTable =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tableView);
        floorPlan = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.floor_plan);
        saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);

        for (int i = 0;i<15;i++) {
            TableView tv = new TableView(MainActivity.this, numberOfSeats, tableId, positionX, positionY, objectWidth, objectHeight
                    , isTaken, tableKind);
            tv.setTag(i);
            positionX +=25;
            positionY +=34;
            //tv.setY(positionY);
            //tv.setX(positionX);

            floorPlan.addView(tv);
        }






        floorPlan.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if (insertTableCheck) {

                    saveBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    int x = (int)motionEvent.getX()-objectWidth/2;
                    int y =(int) motionEvent.getY()-objectHeight/2;

                    Log.i(TAG, "insertTable: insertingTable on: " + x + " " + y);

                    TableView tav = new TableView(MainActivity.this,numberOfSeats,tableId,x,
                            y,objectWidth,objectHeight,isTaken,tableKind);
                    tav.setX(x);
                    tav.setY(y);

                    floorPlan.addView(tav);
                    /*TextView tableForInsert = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    tableForInsert.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tableForInsert.setWidth(objectWidth);
                    tableForInsert.setHeight(objectHeight);
                    tableForInsert.setX(x);
                    tableForInsert.setY(y);
                    floorPlan.addView(tableForInsert);*/
                    insertTableCheck = false;

                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onTouch: just clicked on layout");

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Note that for loop and the data above is just for testing! Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: First off-  why are you extending View?  If you have children, it needs to expand ViewGroup.  Second, this kind of design is really, really a bad fit for Android.  Is the server taking into account the screen size and dpi of your device?  If not, it will look like shit on most devices.

Comment: My experience with drawing on android is not that big so i had to start from somewhere. Figured that this is the way to go. Server is not taking that into account atm, i am just trying to draw and add everything properly for now. The point of this is for the server to store something like a floor plan which will be later read on more than one device. Do you have a suggestion on what logic should i use if this is bad? Thanks for the reply.